# Adsense get recommendations in JSON, it possible?

Tags: javascript, json, ads, adsense

can I get from AdSense recommendations in Json? Like this:

```
    [
   {
      "title": "Example",
      "image": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
      "link": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
   },
   {
      "title": "Example2",
      "image": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
      "link": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
   },
   {
      "title": "Example3",
      "image": "http://placehold.it/32x32",
      "link": "http://placehold.it/32x32"
   }
]
```

I want create custom ad block on my site with my styles.